# What is the simplest way and most reliable way to make a text lay on top of an image (GWT, CSS)?

Tags: html, css, gwt

Ok, I have a mail icon for the message system. Whenever there is a new incomming message, the system will count the number of messages & show that number on top of the mail icon.

He is in xml file

```
<g:FlowPanel addStyleNames="{res.css.flowInline}">                                  
    <g:Image ui:field="privateMessageImage" addStyleNames="{res.css.mailIcon}"
 url="/images/icon/mail.png" title="Private Message" />
    <g:Label text="6" addStyleNames="{style.privateMessageNumber}" />    
</g:FlowPanel>
```

The result is like this:

```
________
|__\/__|6
```

That is not what i want cos the number `6` is right at the end of the mail icon.

So I want it look like this

```
________
|6_\/__|
```

Here is css

```
.privateMessageNumber{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:red;  
    font-size: large;   
}
.mailIcon{
    width:37px;
    height:25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}
```

So how to fix it to achieve the desired result.

**Note:***I just want a very reliable css that can work in all browser, I don't need colorful complicated css.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an Image. Set image as a background to your Label.

```
background-image:url('/images/icon/mail.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
background-position:center;
```

Set the width of your Label to be the same as the width of the icon you are using. Use text-align property to position the number where you want it.

Comment: great creative solution, but i fall into other issue, the real image is bigger, so i have to use ".mailIcon" to control the mail image size. Is there anyway to control "background-image"'s size?

Comment: i fixed, just put "background-size: 37px 25px;" in. Thank you very much. I think This is the most elegant solution for text over image.

Comment: There is better way. See my update. If you change your icon, it will still work.

Comment: ok, i changed, that is much better, but do you sure that the background image won't repeat in all browsers ? can we prevent the background image to repeat?

Comment: Add background-repeat:no-repeat;

Comment: actually the Label is not very suitable cos u can't make the Text align top. SO i put background image into HTML & use <sup> to make the text on top. <g:HTML> <sup>45</sup> </g:HTML>. And it rendered quite nicely

Comment: Label translates into a div element. You can use CSS on it too.

Comment: can u give example, how to make the text of label to go to top?

Comment: text-align: has no Top, only "center" or left or "right"

Comment: All HTML elements always align to the top by default. You can style a label anyway you like using CSS properties such as font-size, line-height, and paddings.

Comment: But the whole label is image, if we align it to top then we move the whole image to top

Comment: You are right. You can wrap a Label in another div, and set an image as a background on that div.

Comment: then we go back to relative absolute css solution which is fragile.

Comment: No. Just set heights on your label and your div. A label will align to the top.